# Error with installation of ROS

Tags: software-sources, ros

As I install ROS, it comes with this error:
Ignoring file 'ros-latest-list' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension. What should I do with this file 'ros-latest-list'?

Answer (score 1):

From `man sources.list`:

> Filenames [in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/] need to have either the
>   extension .list or .sources depending on the contained format.

So I would suggest renaming it:

```
sudo mv ros-latest-list ros-latest.list
```

Comment: it succeeds, really thannnnnnks!